# Javascript: I am trying to create dynamic table inside modal for amortization

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

i am trying to create a dynamic table for amortization table but i coudnt append column. it insert row everytime so my every value is in new row and how do i create loop so that my next column should be +1. because this is row(0) so it everytime comes upward and my whole table shows upside down.

i write so far

```
function writeln(str) {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var txt = document.createTextNode(str);
  var row = output.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = str;
}
function main() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= numpayments; ++i) {
    sumpay += payments;
    propertypriceapp = 0.0090 + propertypriceapp;
    var thisint = balance * intrate;
    sumint += thisint;

    var thisprin = payments - thisint;
    sumprin += thisprin;

    balance -= thisprin;

    var curvalequity = sumprin * (1 + propertypriceapp);

    writeln(flushright(i, 5));
      // flushright(fmtmoney(payments), 9) + "  " + 
      // flushright(fmtmoney(thisint), 9) + "  " + 
      // flushright(fmtmoney(thisprin), 8) + "  " + 
      // flushright(fmtmoney(sumpay), 9) + "  " + 
      // flushright(fmtmoney(sumint), 9) + "  " + 
      // flushright(fmtmoney1(sumprin), 9) + "  " + 
      // flushright(fmtmoney(balance), 12) + "   " +
      // flushright(fmtmoney1(curvalequity), 9) + "  " +
      writeln(flushright(fmtmoney1(propertypriceapp), 9));
    // write("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    // writeln("")
  }
}
```

my html code is

```
<table class="modal-body" id="output">
        </table>
```

Comment: where is your loop? your code creates 1 row and 1 column in it

Comment: @AndrewEvt changed the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for above question, 
str is converted into array

```
temp = str.split(" "); // this will split string into ","
```

after that the array used to create a cell < td>

```
var table=document.createElement('TABLE');
table.setAttribute('class','table table-striped table-bordered')//this is bootstraps classes
var tbdy=document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tbdy);
function writeln(str) {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = str.split("  ");
     var tr=document.createElement('TR');
     tbdy.appendChild(tr);
     for (var zxc2=0;zxc2<temp.length;zxc2++){
      var td=document.createElement('TD');
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(temp[zxc2]));
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  output.appendChild(table);
}
```

this way i got my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `writeln` function create 1 row and 1 column each time, when it called.

It have 1 var, that is unusable - `var txt = document.createTextNode(str);` and each time make a call to DOM - `var output = document.getElementById("output");`
It is bad for performance, and code is very difficult to understand.

If you want to create more colums in 1 row, your code must be something like this:

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function writeln(str) {
    // str -> must be array, that have lenght = num of columns, you want to create
    var row = output.insertRow(0),
        len = str.lenght; // count of rows
    // creates rows 
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // create new row
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        // insert HTML code in it
        cell.innerHTML = str[i];    
    }
}
```

If you want to create more rows with columns, you must make it in the loop, and each time change `j` param in `var row = output.insertRow(j),` line.

Comment: look at [link](http://mahavarkar.in/new_amort.html) you will get the idea what i am trying to do.